# JVM version not update in manager web tomcat8 debian

Tags: java-8, debian, tomcat8, debian-jessie

I'm trying to update java version in my server Debian 8 using steps in this [link](https://xmoexdev.com/wordpress/installing-openjdk-8-debian-jessie/).

After checked with run `java -version` and `javac -version`, my java is update correctly.

[image]

[image]

my problem is when I try to check JVM Version is still remain as old version

[image]

Answer (score 0):

update java home in /etc/default/tomcat8

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

And than restart tomcat